# Tacos AjaxEventSubmit doesn't attach necessary javascript for Tapestry Palette component after refresh?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, submit, tapestry

I've got two tacos radio buttons which I use for hiding (1st value) and showing (2nd value)  palette. I am using Tapestry 4.0. In updateComponents, I use "mainForm" which is the standard Form, where all my components are.

Once I switch radio buttons, palette appears or disappears correctly with available set filled up from model.

Problem is that javascript code for select_palette(), deselect_palette() functions is missing, so clicking on arrows between selects doesn't do anything and I see errors in js console.

If I press Save afterwards, which is the standard submit button, then everything is OK and I can start selecting items.

Has anybody come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, solution was easy and obvious.
I have to use tacos:palette instead of contrib:palette, then the whole ajax refresh is correct.